# jQuery when click on the close button it will only hide that particular div only?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this piece of markup. Remember all these are coming from the database. I have used foreach loop and in that I am getting those values

```
<div id="announcment-wrap">
    <div class="announcement-text">
    This is again a dummy 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">|&nbsp;click here</a>
    <a id="close" href="#" class="close">X</a>
  </div>
    <div class="announcement-text">
    This is demo 3 
    <a href="http://www.google.co.in">|&nbsp;Demo3</a>
    <a id="close" href="#" class="close">X</a>
  </div>
    <div class="announcement-text">
    This is demo 4 
    <a href="http://facebook.com">|&nbsp;Demo again</a>
    <a id="close" href="#" class="close">X</a>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Now you can see there is a close button  `<a id="close" href="#" class="close">X</a>`. I want that when someone will click on close button then it will only hide that div()
In jquery when I used

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#close').click(function() {
    jQuery('.announcement-text').hide();
  });
});
```

it is only working for the first block and also it is hiding the total all blocks? So can someone tell me how to make that when someone will click on that close button and it will hide that particular block.Thanks

Comment: You cannot have the same ID for all the anchor elements, Use Class instead.Check my ans

Comment: All close buttons have same ID so it will not work if you try to access all close buttons using Id . Instead of ID access them using class i.e .close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#close').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent('.announcement-text').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ID should be unique so use selector as .close not #lose

Try http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/ZGjaj/

Your each text is

```
<div class="announcement-text">
    This is again a dummy 
    <a href="http://www.google.com">|&nbsp;click here</a>
    <a id="close" href="#" class="close">X</a>
</div>
```

USe

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.close').click(function() { 
    $(this).closest('.announcement-text').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Id's should be unique so use class instead,and try using `.closest()`

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in">|&nbsp;Demo3</a>
<a class="close" href="#" class="close">X</a>
-----^

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.close').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).closest('.announcement-text').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the close button is inside the div, u can make use of the .parent() function to select the div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   jQuery('#close').click(function() {
      jQuery(this).parent().hide();
   });
});
```

all the best!! hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **class** i.e .close  to work for all close close button Or specify different **id** to all of them .

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
      jQuery('.close').click(function(){
jQuery(this).closest('.announcement-text').hide();});});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot have the same ID for all the Close buttons, Remove duplicate ID.
This won;t work in IE7 <

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('.announcement-text').hide();
  });
});
```